# Вывести список картинок на экран, используя запрос по URL

Tags: javascript, http, url, get, fetch

Стоит задача:

> Если числа попадают в диапазон от 1 до 10 — сделать запрос по URL https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=1&limit=10, где GET-параметр `page` — это число из первого input, а GET-параметр `limit` — это введённое число второго input.

Я написал код, но изображение не выводится.

Кроме того, дело в том что каждый `input` имеет свой вывод текста в случае ошибки, и мне удалось это сделать. Но так же если в двух `input` значение не валидны то выводится третий текст (`"Номер страницы и лимит вне диапазона от 1 до 10"`), вот это сообщение не получается вывести.

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.j-btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const page = +document.getElementById('page').value;
  const limit = +document.getElementById('limit').value;

  let s = document.getElementById('j-result');
  s.textContent = '';
  if (!(page >= 1 && page <= 10)) {
    s.textContent = 'Номер страницы вне диапазона от 1 до 10';
    return;
  }
  if (!(limit >= 1 && limit <= 10)) {
    s.textContent = 'Лимит вне диапазона от 1 до 10';
    return;
  }
  if (!(limit >= 1 && limit <= 10 && page >= 1 && page <= 10)) {
    s.textContent = 'Номер страницы и лимит вне диапазона от 1 до 10';
    return;
  }
  // Делаем запрос за данными
  fetch(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`)
    .then((response) => {
      document.getElementById('result').src = response.url;
    });

});
```

```css
.result {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.card-image {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background: #307570;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 2px rgba(141, 150, 178, 0.3);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

legend {
  max-width: 115px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 13px;
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Task-4</title>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Размер картинки</legend>
    <p> <label>Номер страницы</label> <br />
      <input id="page" class="text" size="20" placeholder="Введите число от 1 до 10">
    </p>
    <p> <label>Лимит</label> <br />
      <input id="limit" class="text" size="20" placeholder="Введите число от 1 до 10">
    </p>
    <p> <button class="btn j-btn">Запрос</button> </p>
  </fieldset>
  <div id="j-result"></div>
  <img id="result" />

  <script src="task4.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: надо читать доку внимательно, тебе объект json дают в ответе, а не картинку, а ты объект пихаешь в путь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так решить вашу задачу:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.j-btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const page = +document.getElementById('page').value;
  const limit = +document.getElementById('limit').value;

  let s = document.getElementById('j-result');
  s.textContent = '';
  if (!(page >= 1 && page <= 10)) {
    s.textContent = 'Номер страницы вне диапазона от 1 до 10';
    return;
  }
  if (!(limit >= 1 && limit <= 10)) {
    s.textContent = 'Лимит вне диапазона от 1 до 10';
    return;
  }
  if (!(limit >= 1 && limit <= 10 && page >= 1 && page <= 10)) {
    s.textContent = 'Номер страницы и лимит вне диапазона от 1 до 10';
    return;
  }
  // Делаем запрос за данными
  fetch(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`)
    .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) =>{
        let res = document.querySelector('#j-result');
        for (item of data){
            let img = document.createElement('IMG');
            img.setAttribute('src', item.download_url);
            img.setAttribute('alt', item.author);
            img.setAttribute('width', '200');
            res.append(img);
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.result {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.card-image {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background: #307570;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 2px rgba(141, 150, 178, 0.3);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

legend {
  max-width: 115px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 13px;
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Task-4</title>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Размер картинки</legend>
    <p> <label>Номер страницы</label> <br />
      <input id="page" class="text" size="20" placeholder="Введите число от 1 до 10">
    </p>
    <p> <label>Лимит</label> <br />
      <input id="limit" class="text" size="20" placeholder="Введите число от 1 до 10">
    </p>
    <p> <button class="btn j-btn">Запрос</button> </p>
  </fieldset>
  <div id="j-result"></div>

  <script src="task4.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, вашему fetch не хватает `redirect: 'follow'`, хотя вы и сами могли бы посмореть, что в сетевых запросах в ответ вам приходит "пустышка", а во вторых, обслуживайте запрос правильно.

```
var requestOptions = {
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
     console.log(result);
     // здесь и стартуйте вашу функцию
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```